# How do I make 'datetime' column ordered correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have a column, it's time is 'DATETIME'. I want to output it in the order of timeline, but when I use `ORDER BY create_time DESC`, '2011-09-10 16:16:04' is behind '2011-07-16 03:20:01'.

Seems it is treating datatime column as string.

How can I handle this without changing the column type?

UPDATE:

This is part of my query:

```
SELECT 'bookcomment' AS type
            ,b.book_id
            ,b.name
            ,c.book_id
            ,c.author_id
            ,c.content
            ,c.create_time as create_time
            ,u.id
            ,u.name
            FROM tbl_book AS b,
                        tbl_book_comment AS c,
                        tbl_user AS u
            WHERE u.id=c.author_id in (1,2) AND b.book_id=c.book_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'bookreview' AS type
            ,b.book_id
            ,b.name
            ,re.book_id
            ,re.author_id
            ,re.content
            ,re.create_time as create_time
            ,u.id
            ,u.name
            FROM tbl_book AS b,
                        tbl_book_review AS re,
                        tbl_user AS u
            WHERE u.id=re.author_id in (1,2) AND b.book_id=re.book_id

UNION ALL
...
            ORDER BY create_time DESC
```

And part of the output:

```
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "Whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(4) "test" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-07-16 03:20:01" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(13) "sdfwefwaefwea" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-05-11 03:33:33" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(5) "test0" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-09-10 16:16:04" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(5) "test1" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-09-10 16:16:04" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(5) "test2" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-09-10 16:16:04" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(5) "test3" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-09-10 16:16:04" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "new post comment" ["book_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "whatever" ["author_id"]=> string(5) "test4" ["content"]=> string(19) "2011-09-10 16:16:04" ["create_time"]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: Why would you not want to change the column type to a datetime? This is clearly what the data is.

Comment: I assume you have datetime column's datatype as datetime?

Comment: Even if it's treating the column as a string, the order would be the same. "2011-09" > "2011-07"

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't say that clearly.

Comment: @AndrewVit is correct I checked it works.

Comment: @LotusH then please edit and clear your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have the data in the wrong columns. In your output sample `create_time` is `3` for all of them, so the order is undefined. Double-check data is in the right columns?

Comment: Happened to me once... on a table with 8 million rows, no less!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
ORDER BY CONVERT (create_time, DATETIME) DESC
```

BUT beware that this costs some performance... changing the column type is IMHO the better option !

Comment: @Inca if you check the time of my answer then you can clearly see that at that time the information about column type was NOT available (it was added later by the OP!).